# Pandas to_datetime incorrect result (different types for different rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I use `to_datetime` to format data for DataFrame as following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/79219/Downloads/bd_with_names.csv', sep = ';')
from datetime import datetime, date 
df['data_posledney_pokupki']=df['data_posledney_pokupki'].str.split(' ').str.get(0)
df.head()
df['created_date']=df['created_date'].str.split(' ').str.get(0)
df.head()
```

before I change types data correct.
The output1 are:

```
    user_id created_date    summa_pokupok   kolichestvo_pokupok data_posledney_pokupki
0   0000186661  2018-05-15  760           1                      21.02.2020
1   21_0018542  2017-02-11  1899          1                      11.01.2020
2   17_0069595  2017-11-01  14606   13                           26.06.2020
3   14_0109526  2017-03-18  18334   4                            06.03.2020
```

after I apply `to_datetime`

```py
df['data_posledney_pokupki'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_posledney_pokupki'],format="%Y/%m/%d") 
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'])  
df.head()
```

in some strings days and month switch, in some of them stay in right position:
The output2 are:

```
0   0000186661  2018-05-15  760   1     2020-02-21
1   21_0018542  2017-02-11  1899    1   2020-11-01
2   17_0069595  2017-11-01  14606   13  2020-06-26
3   14_0109526  2017-03-18  18334   4   2020-06-03
```

Data in row[0] still correct, but date in row[1] now wrong.
Where is mistake?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what the problem is here. The column that you are displaying as the example looks fine to me. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Try changing `to_datetime` argument format to `format="%d.%m.%Y" `?

Comment: `'data_posledney_pokupki'` doesn't match the format you specify so it shouldn't be converted to a datetime at all. You should be seeing: `ValueError: time data 21.02.2020 doesn't match format specified`

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that it worked for you even in the cases where it did.

The `format` you provide has to match a [specific format specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), and yours was incorrect.

I see you have 2 formats:

1. `2018-05-15`
2. `21.02.2020`

I presume that (1) is `YYYY-MM-DD` and (2) is `DD.MM.YYYY`.

Therefore, using the info shown in the link above, you *should* have passed:

1. `format="%Y-%m-%d"`
2. `format="%d.%m.%Y"`

Notice:

- The `%Y`, `%m`, etc. are specifications
- Everything else is just as written, so you use a `-` if there is a `-` and a `.` if there is a `.`.

Comment: It doesn't help - even in this way 11 January turns to 1 November.

Comment: No, I think you are confused: there is a [universal date time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) which all date times get converted to. This is what the whole world uses when they want to communicate globally. It is essentially the East Asian format, because it was clearer that European or American formats due to the MM/DD/YYYY vs. DD/MM/YYYY confusion between our formats.

Answer (score 0):

It is in this line. You did not define the format for date string.

```py
# wrong
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'])

# right
df['created_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Same applies to the other date column you are converting. The format you defined is wrong. Instead of `/` your actual date column has `.` as separator between year, month, day, ex.g. `2020.08.01`. It should be reflected in the format you are passing, so it becomes `%Y.%m.%d`.

```py
# wrong
df['data_posledney_pokupki'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_posledney_pokupki'], format="%Y/%m/%d")

# right
df['data_posledney_pokupki'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_posledney_pokupki'], format="%Y.%m.%d")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Even in this case 11 January turns to 1 November, but other dates stay correct

Comment: Initially I don't add format parametr at all, result was the same